# Can the Google +1 Javascript API be used in a way that requests are sent via visitor's PC/IP, and not my web server?

Tags: javascript, api, http-headers, google-plus-one, proxies

Google +1 API reference:  http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/

What I want to do is use the Google+1 API on my website that contains pages with links to other websites.  When a visitor clicks the +1 button next to a link they like, I want the request to come from the user's computer, not from my web server.

My concern is that Google may think the +1s are spammy or whatnot if they all come from my web server, so I want them to appear natural, coming from IPs all over the world.

Hoping that someone who REALLY understands HTTP requests and Javascript can help answer this.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Turns out the JSON request that's sent when the +1 button is clicked contains a field called "container" that contains the source page URL, not the URL that's actually being +1'd.  Also, when the .js files are GET to a visitor's machine, the "Referrer" is set to be the source page URL (of course).

I'm looking for a way to prevent the Referrer and the "container" field from containing the source page URL.

Answer (score 2):

A google +1 link in a web page already comes from the user's computer.  The user is displaying your web page on their computer and when a Google +1 link is clicked, the user's own browser makes the Google +1 request to Google's computers.  Your web site provides the code in the web page, but the user's own computer makes the Google +1 request.  I don't think you need to worry about this issue as your web server is not making the actual Google +1 request.

Comment: But if the +1 javascript is embeded in MY page - <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script> - then won't Google know where the original request came from?

Comment: Yes, they presumably know where the request came from.  Isn't that the point of a plus one button - to recommend your particular page?  As long as it's real users pushing the button from various locations on the internet, everything is fine - that's how it is intended to be used.

Comment: You can specify a "target URL" which can be different than the page that the Google +1 button is on.  That's what I'll be doing.  I'm not getting people to +1 my own pages, I'm getting them to +1 other people's URLs.

Comment: I don't know Google's rules about +1 on things on different domains, but if they're OK with that, then as long as the traffic is coming from a variety of different people's real browsers, the fact that the +1 requests are coming from your page should not be a problem - that's how it's intended to be used. What Google would object to would be your server cranking away on +1 requests without real people behind the requests.

Comment: Yes, Google is ok with having +1 buttons on different domains. I did some testing and it turns out the JSON request that's sent when the +1 button is clicked contains a field called "container" that contains the source page URL, not the URL that's actually being +1'd. Also, when the .js files are GET to a visitor's machine, the "Referrer" is set to be the source page URL (of course). Therefore, I'm looking for a way to prevent the Referrer and the "container" field from containing the source page URL.

Comment: @Kane - why?  It sounds like you're trying to prevent the collecting of environmental information that Google thinks is relevant.